# Convert hover logic to click for mobile devices

Tags: jquery

I have multiple `div` elements which work as I require on hover but because hover doesn't work on mobile devices I want to enable it with click in jQuery. I uploaded the image of what I want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".main").hover(function() {
        $(".blue", this).stop().animate({
            bottom: '0px',
            opacity: '0.5',
        }, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(".blue", this).stop().animate({
            bottom: '-100px',
            opacity: '0.9',
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="main" style="background: #cecece; height: 200px; width: 300px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;">
    <div class="blue" style="font-size: 14px; background: #09bbfd; z-index: 100; height: 150px; width: 300px; bottom: -100px; position: absolute; opacity: 0.9;">
        <h2 style="margin: 12 5 5 5; color: #fcde11;">Lorem ipsum test</h2>
        <p style="margin: 12 5 5 5;">
            Suspendisse potenti. Nam tincidunt congue dignissim. Donec pharetra tincidunt aliquet. Morbi euismod non mi a pulvinar. Mauris leo tellus, tempor laoreet 
        </p>
    </div>
    <img  src="uploads/gad1.jpg" alt="windows" >
</div>
```

[image: What i want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the logic to hide the other `blue` element in the click handler

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".main").click(function() {
        //Hide other
        $(".blue").stop().animate({
            bottom: '-100px',
            opacity: '0.9',
        }, 500);

        //Animate current child element
        $(".blue", this).stop().animate({
            bottom: '0px',
            opacity: '0.5',
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/bafckya8/)

Comment: Works great :) Thank you :))